# Having trouble integrating Facebook into my android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating logging in via Facebook in my app. I have this code that presents the login:

```
Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    // callback when session changes state
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Log.d("s", "SUCCES");
            // make request to;2 the /me API
        }

        if (exception != null) {
            Log.d("s", exception.toString());
        }

        Log.d("s", "state:" + state.toString());
    }
});
```

After I enter my username/password, I get this in the logs:

```
 D/app﹕ com.facebook.FacebookException: Log in attempt aborted.
 D/app﹕ state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED
 D/app﹕ state:OPENING
```

What I've tried:

- Checked my package name is correct
- Checked the hash key is correct (Used the code by facebook)
- Taken my app out of sandbox mode.
- Checked I have the correct app id in my manifest file

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have this problem because you already have an active session. So just test it before trying to reopen it.

```
 Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

// callback when session changes state
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Log.d("s", "SUCCES");
        // make request to;2 the /me API
    }

    if (exception != null) {
        Log.d("s", exception.toString());
    }

    Log.d("s", "state:" + state.toString());
}


Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session!=null && !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
        .setPermissions(...)
        .setCallback(statusCallback));
} else {
    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, statusCallback);
}
```

Comment: you have the same error message ? (i.e. you don't run into `openForRead` ?)

Comment: @0xSina did you see my question ?

Comment: getting a NullPointerException as '!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()' because session is null so we need a null check. I added a null check 'session != null && !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()'

Comment: And with the null check ? What's the result ? Note that according the logs you have posted : it seems that the `callback.call` method is called twice : first time with an exception and the state CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED and second time without exception and the state OPENING.

Comment: Thanks, that worked with null check. I've accepted your answer, will award bounty in 16 hours when it lets me. Thanks again for your help @ben75 !

Answer (score 0):

Reading through Facebook's SDK code we can extract some conclusions.

You get an exception on your callback with a specific message and state. These two are sent only when the close() Session's method is called, while the state was OPENING, which is at the same time called by setActiveSession, and that one gets called directly by your `Session.openActiveSession(...)`

The next thing that  gets called is `session.openForRead(openRequest)`, which calls `open(openRequest, ...)`, with the current state being `CREATED` (default state after building a new session). This sets the new session as the active session through `setActiveSession(session)` which ends up closing the oldSession if there was one active, and here's the thing again, you are getting a FacebookException with a "Log in attempt aborted" on the message, which only gets called if the current state of the previous session was OPENING.

All that means that either you are calling this piece of code twice within a short amount of time or that the authorization process is not going through and ends up on a dead end (most likely).

Before getting deeper on the authorize method I'll double check configuration in facebook (mode, key hashes -different depending on the launching environment: production, degub, etc-, package name and start activity). For simplicity, clear data and caches of your app every time you try (or manually call `closeAndClearTokenInformation()` from your code.

Let's see what comes out to keep digging into the issue.